# Como passar um array de objeto java para a AsyncTask? Meu problema é que quando uso esse looping no AsyncTask pq só vem primeiro usuario [0]

Tags: java, android

```
ControlaBanco bd = new ControlaBanco(contexto);
        int indice = 0;
        indice = bd.contaUsuarios();
        Usuario[ ] tabela = bd.organizaTabela();
        String tabelaOrganizada = "";
        if ( indice > 0 ) {
            for (int i = 0; i < indice; i++) {
                tabelaOrganizada += String.valueOf(tabela[ i ].getId()) + "  ";
                tabelaOrganizada += tabela[ i ].getNome() + "  ";
                tabelaOrganizada += tabela[ i ].getTitulo() + "  ";
                tabelaOrganizada += tabela[ i ].getPTS() + "  ";
                tabelaOrganizada += tabela[ i ].getGraduacao() + "\n";
            }
        }
        int id = 4;
        TableRow.LayoutParams linhaParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final TextView fimRank = new TextView(contexto);
        fimRank.setLayoutParams(linhaParams);
        fimRank.setId(id);
        fimRank.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);
        fimRank.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        fimRank.setText(tabelaOrganizada);
        TableRow.LayoutParams spanparams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        spanparams.span = 4;

        TableRow linha4Tabela = new TableRow(contexto);
        linha4Tabela.setLayoutParams(linhaParams);
        linha4Tabela.setId(id);
        linha4Tabela.addView(fimRank, spanparams);
        containertabela.addView(linha4Tabela);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, antes de tudo agradeço ao @Samuel Ives pela resposta. Mas o problema estava no método organizaTabela () que não estava retornando o array completo porquê a cada objeto que eu ia adicionar ao array eu não estava colocando a seguinte linha de código:

tabela[ i ] = new Usuario();

Eu queria muito por a resposta do Samuel Ives como a certa pelo trabalho que ele teve pra responder mas não foi a resposta que eu usei pra resolver o problema valew.

Answer (score 0):

Até onde eu sei você precisa especificar os tipos que o [asynctask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) vai trabalhar, passe os parâmetros em seu asynctask.execute(o  tipo de entrada se não for void é um array), e recupera em doInBackground(Params...), onde Params... é um array do tipo que você especificou, então recupere como um array, exemplo `String str = params[0];`

**Editado:**

Para simplificar vou deixar um exemplo do meu app

PageTask é uma interface que uso para recuperar os dados:

package com.samuelives.videoplayer.system;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface PageTask {

    public void finishDownload(ArrayList<String>data);

}
```

PageDownloader é meu Asynctask responsável por extrair dados de uma página:

```
package com.samuelives.videoplayer.system;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;

import com.samuelives.videoplayer.R;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class PageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<String>>{

    private PageTask mPt;
    private Context mContext;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;

    public PageDownloader(PageTask pt, Context context){
        this.mPt = pt;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.i("Page Downloader", "Baixando pagina da web...");
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        mProgress.setTitle(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.pageDownloader_proDlgTitle));
        mProgress.setMessage(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.pageDownloader_proDlgInitialMessage));
        mProgress.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... strings) {

        ArrayList<String>content = new ArrayList<>();

        try{

            Document page = null;
            String ua = getUserAgent();

            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(strings[0]).userAgent(ua).execute();

            if(testConnection(response)){
                page = Jsoup.connect(strings[0]).userAgent(getUserAgent()).get();

                String videoSrc = getVideoSource(page);

                content.add(0, videoSrc);
                content.add(1, getVideoTitle(page));

                if(Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(videoSrc).matches()){
                    content.add(2, getVideoMime(videoSrc));
                }else{
                    content.add(2, "null");
                }

            }else{
                content.add(0,"null");
                content.add(1,"null");
                content.add(2,"null");
            }


        }catch (IllegalArgumentException | IOException e){
            Log.e("Could connect to page", e.getMessage());
        }

        return content;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> strings) {
        super.onPostExecute(strings);

        mProgress.dismiss();

        Log.i("Page Downloader", "Download completo");
        Log.i("Video src", strings.get(0));
        Log.i("Video title", strings.get(1));
        Log.i("Video MIME", strings.get(2));

        mPt.finishDownload(strings);

    }

    private boolean testConnection(Connection.Response response){


        //Check if exist response of connection
        if(response != null){

            //Check if connection is OK
            if(response.statusCode() != 200){

                Log.e("Page downloader", "Failed to connect, Response Code: " + response.statusCode());
                return false;

            }else{

                Log.i("Page downloader", "Connection OK");
                return true;

            }


        }else{

            Log.e("Page downloader", "Error, have not response of connection!");
            return false;

        }

    }

    private String getVideoSource(Document doc){

        try {

            Element videoSrc = doc.getElementsByTag("video").first();
            Element sourceSrc = null;
            if (videoSrc != null) {

                if(videoSrc.attr("src") != null){
                    return videoSrc.attr("src");
                }else{
                    sourceSrc = videoSrc.getElementsByTag("source").first();
                    if(sourceSrc != null){

                        if(sourceSrc.attr("src") != null){
                            return sourceSrc.attr("src");
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            Log.e("Page downloader", "Failed to get source: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return "null";
    }

    private String getVideoTitle(Document doc){

        String title = "videoplayback";

        try {

            Element titleTag = doc.getElementsByTag("title").first();
            if((titleTag != null) && (titleTag.text() != null)){
                title = titleTag.text();
            }

        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            Log.e("Page downloader", "Could get page title: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return title;
    }

    private String getVideoMime(String input){

        String mimeType = "null";
        URL url = null;

        try {

            url = new URL(input);

            if(URLUtil.isHttpsUrl(input)){

                Log.d("Page downloader", "HTTPS Url source.");

                HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", getUserAgent());

                String ct = con.getContentType();

                if((ct.equals("text/html")) || (ct.equals("application/xhtml+xml")) || (ct.equals("text/php")) || (ct.equals("application/php")) || (ct.equals("application/x-php") || (ct.equals("text/x-php")))){

                    if(con.getHeaderField("Location") != null){

                        String urlLocation = con.getHeaderField("Location");
                        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(urlLocation);
                        if(extension != null){
                            mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                        }

                    }

                }else{

                    mimeType = con.getContentType();

                }

                con.disconnect();

            }else{

                Log.d("Page downloader", "HTTPS Url source.");

                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", getUserAgent());

                String ct = con.getContentType();

                if((ct.equals("text/html")) || (ct.equals("application/xhtml+xml")) || (ct.equals("text/php")) || (ct.equals("application/php")) || (ct.equals("application/x-php") || (ct.equals("text/x-php")))){

                    if(con.getHeaderField("Location") != null){

                        String urlLocation = con.getHeaderField("Location");
                        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(urlLocation);
                        if(extension != null){
                            mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                        }

                    }

                }else{

                    mimeType = con.getContentType();

                }

                con.disconnect();

            }

        }catch (NullPointerException | IOException e){
            Log.e("Page downloader", "Could get mimetype: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return mimeType;
    }

    private String getUserAgent(){

        String ua = null;
        boolean isTablet = mContext.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);

        if(!isTablet){

            ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE + "; Mobile; rv: 41.0) Gecko/41.0 Firefox/41.0";
            Log.d("User-Agent", ua);

        }else{

            ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE + "; Tablet; rv: 41.0) Gecko/41.0 Firefox/41.0";
            Log.d("User-Agent", ua);

        }

        return ua;

    }

}
```

Note que quando eu extendo minha classe ao AsyncTask eu especifico os parâmetros de entrada e saída Note que String é o parâmetro de entrada pois é uma URL o segundo parâmetro é o tipo de dado para o progresso e ArrayList é o tipo de dado resultante com os dados extraídos que recupero em onPostExecute para minha interface.

E este é o fragmento em que executo a asynctask:

```
package com.samuelives.videoplayer.fragments;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.samuelives.videoplayer.R;
import com.samuelives.videoplayer.player.Player;
import com.samuelives.videoplayer.system.PageDownloader;
import com.samuelives.videoplayer.system.PageTask;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.content.Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements PageTask{

    private Button btnOpenUrl = null;
    private EditText etInputUrl = null;
    private PageDownloader mPageDownloader = null;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mPageDownloader = new PageDownloader(this, getActivity());
        btnOpenUrl.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        etInputUrl = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.etInputUrl);
        btnOpenUrl = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.btnOpenUrl);

        return layout;
    }

    private View.OnClickListener btnListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(etInputUrl.getText().toString() != null){

                if(Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(etInputUrl.getText().toString()).matches()){

                    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                    if((activeNetwork != null) && (activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting())){
                        processUrl(etInputUrl.getText().toString());
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.toastConnectionOffline, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }else{

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.toastInvalidUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.toastEmptyUrl), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void finishDownload(ArrayList<String> data) {

        if((data.get(0) != null) && (data.get(0).equals("null")) && (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(data.get(0)).matches())) {
            Intent it = new Intent(getActivity(), Player.class);
            it.putExtra("videoSrc", data.get(0));
            it.putExtra("videoTitle", data.get(1));
            it.putExtra("videoMime", data.get(2));
            startActivity(it);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.toastNoContent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private void processUrl(String url){

        if(isWatchOnlyWifi()){

            if(!connectionIsWifi()){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.toastOnlyWatchWifi), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;

            }else{

                if(!url.isEmpty()) {

                    if (url.contains(".mp4") || url.contains(".3gp") || url.contains(".ogv")) {

                        Intent it = new Intent(getActivity(), Player.class);
                        it.putExtra("videoTitle", "Video Playback");
                        it.putExtra("videoSrc", url);
                        startActivity(it);

                    } else {

                        mPageDownloader = new PageDownloader(this, getActivity());
                        mPageDownloader.execute(url);

                    }

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.toastEmptyUrl), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }


        }else {

            if(!url.isEmpty()) {

                if (url.contains(".mp4") || url.contains(".3gp") || url.contains(".ogv")) {

                    Intent it = new Intent(getActivity(), Player.class);
                    it.putExtra("videoTitle", "Video Playback");
                    it.putExtra("videoSrc", url);
                    startActivity(it);

                } else {

                    mPageDownloader = new PageDownloader(this, getActivity());
                    mPageDownloader.execute(url);

                }

            }else{

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.toastEmptyUrl), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }

    private boolean isWatchOnlyWifi(){
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        return prefs.getBoolean("pref_key_is_watch_only_wifi", false);
    }

    private boolean connectionIsWifi(){

        try {
            ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo info = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

            if (info.isConnected()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            Log.e("Main", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Eu passo os parâmetros e executo a tarefa com execute() onde o valor de entrada é um array do tipo que você especificou, quando a tarefa termina o método da minha interface que estou implementando `finishDownload(ArrayList<String> data)` é chamado recuperando os dados, é isso, não tem muito segredo, eu levei um tempo para entender o funcionamento também.

[Este vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtFlqrhPn0U) me ajudou muito a compreender o asynctask.

Comment: Na classe ControlaBanco que é responsável por acessos ao bd tem um método que retorna esse array de objetos, então na AsyncTask eu chamo esse método mas pelo jeito esse objeto não chega completo lá sempre passa só o primeiro índice que é usuario [0]. Se eu chamar esse método na minha activity pra passar os usuários como parâmetro na asynctask pode travar o app quando o banco tiver muitos usuários. Eu preciso carregar eles da Async mesmo. Mas valeu por responder.

Comment: @GustavoAlmeidaCavalcante eu coloquei um exemplo de AsyncTask do meu app para você entender melhor.

Comment: Obrigado mas já resolvi.